# Calling a dll function inside a C++ program

Tags: c++

I have a created two new C++ projects. One of them is a C++ .dll project and the other is console application project.

For the dll program, here's the simple code (**.cpp file**):

```
PIPESTOSPACES_API int npipesToSpaces=0;

PIPESTOSPACES_API int fnpipesToSpaces(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

I have to call these dll functions and I am doing this through exporting the function from my C++ file, and implicit linking in my C++ console application. 
It would be great if some could mention the steps on how to call these exported .dll function in the C++ console application. I referred [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm) page to learn exporting the function etc.

EDIT:
I am currently using Visual C++  for all this stuff on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: what compiler are you using? Gcc ? ms ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore there're plenty of compilers able to generate DLLs. Well, maybe Gcc isn't one of them ^^.

Comment: For Visual Studio stuffs, there's another option. 
If my memory doesn't fail on me, you can generate a static lib stub for the DLL and then add it to the project. Done this a very long time ago. However Luchian answer is 100% the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include the header, you can directly call the function because you know the prototype and import the library.

If not, you call `LoadLibrary`, get the dll's handle, and `GetProcAddress` and call the function as a callback.

Comment: I added the C++ dll generated into my console applcation project. However, when I try to include the header "Sampledll.h", it gives me an error: `Cannot open include file: 'Sampledll.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: @user1240679 in your VS project check that directory in which Sampledll.h is located is in the include path.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I added it directly in the root path itself. However, it still gives the same error. In the link that I have in the post which I followed, that guy does linking with `.lib` as well. Is that to be done also? Kind of lost in the steps

Comment: @user1240679 yes, you have to link that library and also include the path to the header in your extra include directories of your project settings.

Comment: Can you please give an example on how we should use GetProcAddress?